# "bower install" and "bower update" showing error

Tags: angularjs, bower, bower-install

Here is my bower.json. I pulled my project from Github, bower files was updated on ubuntu 14.04. But after taking a pull. my angular version is showing 1.4.8 in bower.json file. But inside bower_components there is the angular 1.4.14. So I ran "bower update". But it ended showing "**ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular**". I tried deleting bower_components and ran bower install, but still same problem comes up. my nodejs version is 6.9.1 and I installed it recently. What should I do now? Please give me a solution.

```
{
  "name": "starter-gulp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Starter Code for Gulp Angular ",
  "authors": [
    "John Papa"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/..-gulp",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.8",
    "sinon": "http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.12.1.js",
    "bardjs": "~0.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.8",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.1.0",
    "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "dndLists#~1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.8",
    "angular-summernote": "~0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "bootflat": "*",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "extras.angular.plus": "~0.9.2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.5.0",
    "Ionicons": "ionicons#~2.0.1",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "jquery-quick-pagination": "*",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.4",
    "moment": "~2.8.4",
    "remodal": "~1.0.6",
    "summernote": "~0.7.0",
    "toastr": "~2.1.0",
    "vunit": "~0.2.0",
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "angular-ui-tree": "^2.15.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.0.4",
    "ng-img-crop": "ngImgCrop#^0.3.2",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

==============================================

```
bower bootflat#*                                 progress remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
bower bootflat#*                                 resolved https://github.com/flathemes/bootflat.git#affdd96590
bower bootstrap#~3.3.6                            install bootstrap#3.3.7
bower                                         postinstall gulp wiredep
bower                                         postinstall [23:03:25]
bower                                         postinstall Using gulpfile E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\web-module\gulpfile.js
bower                                         postinstall [23:03:25]
bower                                         postinstall Starting 'wiredep'...
bower                                         postinstall [23:03:25] Wire bower css, js and our app js into html
bower                                         postinstall [23:03:25]
bower                                         postinstall gulp-inject 49 files into index.html.
bower                                         postinstall [23:03:25] Finished 'wiredep' after 401 ms

bootstrap#3.3.7 bower_components\bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.4
```

Also after "npm install" I get these lines, I am confused about it, though its just a warning.something is said about os. **asked for 'darwin' but current 'win32'**. is that a problem.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN gulp-jshint@2.0.2 requires a peer of jshint@2.x but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it means, some component requirement is not met. For example angular-mocks version is 1.3.8 has dependency to angular 1.3.8. Try change to something like:

```
"angular-mocks" : "1.4.8"
```

**Edit:**

From [fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) page:

> The FSEvents API in OS X allows applications to register for
>   notifications of changes to a given directory tree.

so it is not applicable if you are running Windows. If you want to run without any notifications:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

If `bower` does not give you prompt to select a software components version, it means `bower` is able to select it automatically for you. So nothing to worry.

Comment: I tried to do that but didn't help to solve this problem. Anyway I again tried deleting all node and bower files and  reinstalling nodejs and run npm install, but got a new error. I have added some end part of the error by editing my post. Please take a look and give me some suggestion.

Comment: Hello Zamrony, I again tried your way, now I get it solved. Thank you very much for help. But I have a confusion. This time I ran bower update, it didn't offer me to choose angular version at the end. I have attached the result.